# Can't get facebook score using the Javascript API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a little problem getting scores from facebook.
I can post them using the example below:

```
FB.api('/me/scores/', 'post', { score: myScore }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

But then I try to receive scores from facebook I get an OAuthException 104:
"An access token is required to request this resource."

I use the following code to receive scores:

```
FB.api('/MYAPPID/scores/', 'get', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Shouldn't the access_token be sent by the sdk itself?

Answer (score 2):

Just add : `FB.setAccessToken({USER_TOKEN});`

Example :

```
FB.setAccessToken({USER_TOKEN});
FB.api('/me/scores/', 'post', { score: 1000 }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    FB.api('/{APP_ID}/scores/', 'get', function(response2) {
        console.log(response2);
    });
});
```

You can get userAccessToken with `USER_TOKEN = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];`

Full example :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.3'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
            FB.setAccessToken(access_token);
            FB.api('/me/scores/', 'post', { score: 1000 }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                FB.api('/{APP_ID}/scores/', 'get', function(response2) {
                    console.log(response2);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```